# Adding class to parent using CSS instead of Javascript

Tags: css, html

If checkbox is checked then add a CSS class to parent without using Javascript.

Here is tried code:

CSS code:

```
span:focus~.to-be-changed {
  color: red;
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<p class="to-be-changed">I'm going to be red! It's gonna be legen... Wait for it...</p>
<span tabindex="0">Click me!</span>
<p class="to-be-changed">I'm going to be red! It's gonna be legen... Wait for it...</p>
```

Comment: I apologize, please explain your question in an understandable way.so that you can achieve your solution.

Comment: That's no checkbox. It's a hijacked `span`.

Comment: are you allowed to change the html part?

Comment: There is currently no way to select the parent of an element in CSS. It can be done only with help of javascript or jquery.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way if you allow to change your html markup. Use `flex` in the parent container and its `order` property to shuffle the child elements.

```css
span:focus~.to-be-changed {
  color: red;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

span {
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span tabindex="0">Click me!</span>
  <p class="to-be-changed">I'm going to be red! It's gonna be legen... Wait for it...</p>
  <p class="to-be-changed" style="order:3;">I'm going to be red! It's gonna be legen... Wait for it...</p>
</div>
```